# Existing Type in C# that distuingishes between Null values and missing values?

Tags: c#, types, null, optional-parameters

For a "partial update" API I'm looking for a Type that can distinguish between:

- a value
- null
- not specified

Someone could post this to update both *kind* and *description*:

```
{
    kind: "lolcat",
    description: "monorailcat"
}
```

It could use this to reset description to null, BUT leave the original *kind property* alone:

```
{
    description: null
}
```

I am using ASP.NET Core and in the modelbinding I will abstract the details away. For now I'm looking for a Type that I can use as input parameters in my *Actions*, i.e.:

```
public void Update(Optional<string> name, Optional<int?> maxAmountOfLegs) 
{ 
     if ( maxAmountOfLegs.IsDefined ) // if not true, don't update the value
          Entity.MaxAmountOfLegs = maxAmountOfLegs; // value can be null
     [...]
}
```

I can create this type myself, but as I think this is quite a common pattern I want to check if there's anything there already before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a built in type, thought you might want to search the web for "Implementing the maybe monad in c#" or something along these lines. Personally, as an OOP developer, I recommend [this blog post](https://mikhail.io/2018/07/monads-explained-in-csharp-again/) as a good, solid explanations of monads. As a bonus, the author is using the maybe pattern as an example of a monad in his post.

Comment: What difference is the difference between "null" and "not specified"? Usually, Maybe/Option/nullable types only have "Value|NoValue"-states, if you need a third state you probably need to roll your own.

Comment: If you don't want to change the value, then don't set the property, entity will track which property is modified, read this: [PropertyEntry.IsModified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyentry.ismodified?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-changetracking-propertyentry-ismodified)